# Simulate a website

Tags: simulation

Consider a website with two drop down boxes. The second drop down box is populated by ajax depending on the first drop down box's selection. Now can I have a script or program to simulate the various selections of the first drop down box and record the values in the second drop down box correspondingly? Is there any program to simulate inputs to a website and get the outputs automatically. I am a newbie and please excuse me if my question is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking wether there is software to **Simulate a user that interacts with a website**:

Have a look at [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [watin for dotnet](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You may either try Free Web Hosting Companies or try running it on a local server by installing IIS or Apache Tomcat. There are many tutorials to get a local server running.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) is incredibly powerful if you fancy a bit of [Behaviour Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development). It can be a little daunting at first, but I highly recommend this approach due to a very simple and descriptive domain language and benefits like the ability for anyone to write a test, the [portability across platfoms/languages](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/) and ability to easily switch between simulating using a real browser or "headless" (using in-memory browser built on top of [HTML unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/))

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I recommend, jsunit: https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit